# How to set volume in iOS and avoid system volume popup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I use `[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:]` to set volume of playback, but I don't want system volume popup (the one that appears when you control the volume with volume up/down buttons on a device) to appear.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html